# Storing hashmap data in application

Tags: android, static, hashmap, final

I want to store my HashMap inside my application so everytime i restart the application i can retrieve my HashMap. I've seen many ways via Google but what is the most efficient way to do it in my case?

Comment: Efficient in terms of time/space/both/other? How are we supposed to know what "your case" is when you haven't told us?

Comment: I meant, I just want to store an HashMap, nothing more.

Comment: Does the HashMap ever change? i.e. will you be adding values to it dynamically, or will it remain constant throughout the app's lifecycle?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the preferences if the amount of data is not to big. Convert your HashMap to JSON (maybe via gson) and than store it as a string.

If you have a lot of data you need to access fast you can use the integrated sqlite database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `HashMap` as a means of retrieving constant data (i.e. the values inside the `HashMap` won't change), it is as simple as initializing the `HashMap` in your code as follows:

```
private static final Map map = new HashMap();

static {
    map.put(...);
    map.put(...);
    /* etc... */
}
```

If you want this information to be globally accessible, you can create a subclass of `Application` and initialize it there instead.

Comment: I want to write the data into disk so that whenever I restart the application data won't be lost.